# MYSQL order by date or primary key?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with an auto-increment primary key column and a datetime column. I want to return rows ordered by the date they were created.

Does it matter if I order by the date or the primary key? I imagine that it's a faster by primary key opposed to a date format of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` or a timestamp. New records will have greater primary keys. Yet everyone orders by date fields.

Comment: what do you mean by everyone order by date field?

Comment: I mean in most queries programmers order by date but the primary key records time as well.

Comment: Does datetime field hold the current date and time when the records are inserted??

Comment: @Sabin when they are created. The datetime remains unchanged as do the primary keys.

Comment: So i don't think it really doesnt matter whatever you use to sort, if you index date field that will work faster as well. Personally I use the primary key auto increment field to sort. 
Edit: If you are inserting multiple rows at same time, its likely both records have same datetime value.. but different primary key , so its better use auto increment column for sorting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Order by the date field, but make sure to put an index on the date field.

A date field is a binary field, it's just as fast as the primary key. (A date is 3 bytes vs an integer primary key which is 4.) It does not use a string to order it as you appear to assume.

And more importantly it indicates your intent, (plus it's possible for the primary key to wrap around).

Also, if you use innodb it's completely possible for the primary key not to be in order depending on how transactions interleave.

Also, if you are skilled at reading query plans add the date column to the end of the same index that is used for the query. However this only applies in specific situations, so only do it when you know it will help. i.e. don't just do it blindly.

Comment: Is it as fast as even if the date field isn't indexed?

Comment: @bfavaretto No. You have to index it. The fastest is to order by an index you are already using for the search. So check your query plan, then add the date field to the search index. (Doing this right can be tricky, and you have to know databases well. Most of the time just add an index on the date field and stop there.)

Comment: @Ariel, that's what I was just going to note. You should state that in the answer I think.